# Best practice CSS - SASS

Tags: css, sass

I am looking to the wisdom of the crowd for views on best practice for implementing CSS.

Our site was initially built using SASS compilers for CSS. Over time as more functionality has been added, each with specific styles, the CSS files and partials have become large. Loading all CSS for the entire site seems a waste of resources and time, particularly when a large percent is not utilised on any given page. However I am still told that this is more efficient than either inline styles or CSS style blocks within the page.

I am currently considering stripping down everything but core CSS to the SASS CSS file and then creating a series of specific CSS files that are loaded as required.

How have others approached this problem. Is there a consensus on the "best practice" when CSS files become large?

Thanks

D

Comment: This question is either too broad, **opinion based** or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: Thank you and yes I am actually looking for opinion and discussion from experienced practitioners on the subject matter. Are you able to suggest somewhere else that I may be able to ask such a question?

Comment: There nay not be a place on Stack Exchange but feel free to check around. Discussions and opinion questions are, unfortunately, not suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Or perhaps some of the Chat Rooms

Comment: Thanks. 

I don't think it is particularly helpful in whoever giving Loji a -1 when responding to my question in the way that I asked it and proving an answer that I found useful.

Comment: @Dave the best way to counteract the down vote, is to up vote it yourself, then Loji will get points.  I have been downvoted in the past in a similar way and I think it is because people think we shouldn't answer broad questions, but I personally think there is no harm and great to help fellow developers.

Comment: @katie I totally agree with you. I did upvote him but because i don't have sufficient status it doesn't display publically

Answer (score 0):

You can write SASS only for specific parts of your site and load styles for specific pages only. For example you don't have to load styles for product list when you are on product page. 
In the meantime you can have global stylesheet for something like menu, footer.

Loading styles inline or in  block prevents styles from caching and makes your user download it each time they open website.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Loji. 

So you suggest one option is to continue to use SASS but create a series of separately compiled CSS files in addition to style.css that are loaded as required?

Is SASS compiled CSS viewed as more efficient than non compiled?

If there any problem of using a compiled SASS style.css file with non compiled specific CSS files?

Thanks again

Comment: Yes, if one part of your site is much bigger it is good to load its CSS separately only when needed. SASS compiled to CSS is only more efficient if it is minified. There is no difference between normal CSS and SASS compiled CSS if it's minified. And no, there is no problem when you use SASS and CSS. SASS is compiled to normal CSS anyway, only difference is ease of development.

Answer (score 0):

This is the perfect opportunity to clean up your styles and start fresh. I would reccomend you create  `layout.scss` for styles used in all pages, and `component_X.scss` for specific component styles.